# Adding intermediate page to navigate out of the current site

Tags: web-application, appsec

Can someone recommend me the best design to use to navigate out of the site.
Here are the steps to navigate out of the current site.

1)Show the intermediate page warning the user that, they will be navigating out of this site.
2)Also explain them that, navigating out will logoff from the current session.
3)New site should open in a separate tab/popup.
4)Original site should be logged off or session should be invalidated.

In one of the usecase, user is not logged in, but they will submit series of forms, at one stage, if the user is not qualified to navigate further, they will be navigated out of the site to different site. At this stage I would like to kill the server side session associated with the user before they are navigated out of the site.
I am posting this in the security forum because this can potentially lead to DOS attack.

When I think about implementing this,I have to submit multiple forms, one to invalidate the session on the original site and the other one to  navigate to the new site..

Let me know how I can achive this securely.
Thanks

Comment: I've always found these "you're leaving the site" pages stupid and annoying. Assuming the real destinations of the links are clearly visible, I don't see why you would need that.

Comment: One of the main reason for having the intermediate page is that, two sites have differnt level of security controls/trust.Example If you are navigating out of  the bank site to rewards site, they both have differnt levels of trust..

Comment: @AndréDaniel Also an open redirect can be used to craft URLs that look safe but lead to malicious sites, e.g. `https://myback.com/redirect.php?http%3A%2F%2Fbadguys.com`. Many naive users are easily fooled by this. Some advanced users may also be tricked, because most browsers that show link destinations will truncate the end of a very long link.